# Facebook App - Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

The App is public and it has been granted the appropriate permissions:
[Display of app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqPNP.png)

My logged in user is an administrator to the App: [Display of user permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuYbs.jpg)

The code is as follows:

```
import facebook
import warnings



# Hide deprecation warnings. The facebook module isn't that up-to-date (facebook.GraphAPIError).
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)


# Parameters of your app and the id of the profile you want to mess with.
FACEBOOK_APP_ID     = 'SECRET'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'SECRET'
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID = 'SECRET'

fb_api=facebook.GraphAPI()
api_token=fb_api.get_app_access_token(app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, app_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, offline=True)

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(api_token)
# Try to post something on the wall.
try:
    fb_response = graph.put_object(parent_object=FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID, connection_name='feed',
                     message='Hello, world')
    print(fb_response)
except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
    print('Something went wrong:', e.type, e.message)
```

This code fails with the error message:
OAuthException (#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

I am certain at this point I have followed all the things I've read in any other post. The docs they have for the sdk are [here](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/blob/469771cdaabbf5111cb84b1f4a6be536edefb687/docs/api.rst).

Comment: `get_app_access_token` sounds like you're getting just that here, an app access token. Posting using an app token might have worked in the past, but now you will need to use a user or page access token.

Comment: I'm going to have to rig up puppeteer or selenium then which is like, hyper hyper lame

Comment: Also not allowed, and likely to get you blocked when caught. Why can't you get the proper kind of token, if you have a legitimate use case to post?

Comment: In the grand scheme it's not legitimate. But it's also not malicious or widely impactful. A number of sites allow access to them in a unique way if the referer is facebook. But it goes beyond just setting a referer, it's not in the link parameters either so far as I can tell. It might be a unique key or something set in local storage or a cookie of some sort. It seems to be something that's intentionally obfuscated. It should be easy enough though to just post to facebook and then follow the link. It must be pretty recent that app's cannot do this as there are a number of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of stuff is just not working so here's what I did. I created a link and then I just click on it:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

This is super duper easy with something like laravel or lumen. You just make a controller and a route that points to it.

I upload the token to a local consul instance so I can access it across a variety of micro services.

I use puppeteer to login to facebook via my stub site and then I have a token and login cookies too.

Answer (score 0):

we found facebook change the permission requirements for posting to pages from just manage_pages to require both manage_pages and publish_pages. by granting both permissions we solved our problem

in essence we had to pass the client to
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=*client_id*&redirect_uri=*redirect_uri*&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages&response_type=code%20token&enable_profile_selector=1&profile_selector_ids=*pageid*